# how to use isset in laravel Form::text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am trying to get work the following code.

```
{!! Form::text('{$field}', 
(isset($TourDate)) ? date('d/m/Y', strtotime($TourDate)) : 
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['{$field}'])), 
array('class'=>'form-control date')) !!}
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong?

The error code is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is good practice to pass the resulting value from the controller, instead of doing the calculation in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It is in  SiteHelpers.php. Where do I need to put `;` exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the blade `{}` from `{$field}` as you are already in the php scope. So the code is like:

```
{!! Form::text($field, 
(isset($TourDate)) ? date('d/m/Y', strtotime($TourDate)) : 
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row[$field])), 
array('class'=>'form-control date')) !!}
```

Comment: Enjoy the coding :D